# heroku's deploy fauilure for typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku

I tried for the whole time of today about this

my heroku throws weird application error.

it tells me

```
2021-02-04T09:45:48.903514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: node dist/index.js`
2021-02-04T09:45:50.627249+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-02-04T09:45:50.664824+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-04T09:45:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-02-04T09:46:05.479439+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=floating-peak-93538.herokuapp.com request_id=39c6722c-44c8-44b3-b34c-ec73cb2e786f fwd="115.143.126.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-04T09:46:05.778879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=floating-peak-93538.herokuapp.com request_id=9123763b-b7e3-473d-bb66-073b96ea8c3b fwd="115.143.126.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

but when I tried like "tsc" and "node dist/index.js" it worked.

though heroku doing the same thing, It showed me that error. why

I really don't want to use typescript anymore

<package.json>

```
{
  "name": "react-ts-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "fullstack project server",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "engine": {
    "node": "14.15.4",
    "npm": "6.14.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node dist/index.js",
    "deploy": "git add . && git commit -m Heroku && git push heroku master",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Anderson",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/express": "4.11.1",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.14",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

-Procfile-

```
web : node dist/index.js
```

-tsconfig.json-

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts", "src/index.ts"]
}
```